# How to update page variables with ajax and pagemethods?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms, pagemethods

Is there any way to update instance variables from a page method without making them static?

My page has a ViewModel object that contains lots of data that I would like to update ajax and pagemethods. I use the ViewModel in the asp.net front-end page to print out variable values.

**ViewModel Class**

```
  // ViewModel class
   public class ItemViewModel
   {
      public List<Item> Items = new List<Item>();
   }
```

**** ASP.net webforms page (backend)****

```
   public ItemViewModel ViewModel;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // init ViewModel;
    }



     [WebMethod]
        public static bool GetItems(string userId)
        {
            // lots of code...
            ItemService i = new ItemService();

            ViewModel = i.GetItems(userId);  // How to update page variables or pass in a new one?

            return true;
        }
```

**Front-end**

```
                 <ul>
                        <% foreach (Item i in ViewModel.Items)
                           {  %>        
                                <li>
                                   <%=i.ItemName %>
                                </li>
                        <% } %>
                    </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Session state is possible as it is carried over multiple pages, but you will have to make sure that when a user switches a pages at any given time, the Session-data is cleared because else it will be used on next pageload (unless that is what you want).

You could also have your method build a htmlstring that is pasted into your page:

```
public string myFunc()
{
     string html = "<li>foo</li";
     html += "<li>foo2</li>";

     return html;
}
```

And then in your ajax `success` callback you can do:

```
success: function(data) {
       $("#myUL").html(data);
});
```

It works, but it does require you to build a html string by hand, which gets exponentially harder if you have to handle more than a onedimensional array.

I would suggest using JSON in combination with Ajax. It's the easist way to pass whatever you want, and still be able to handle the data rather than just have it pasted as html.

http://www.learn-ajax-tutorial.com/Json.cfm

I would suggest reading through this tutorial, it gives you a good idea on how JSON is built and handled.

Comment: I think the idea of creating the html server-side or at least generating all the page data and using in conjunction with JQuery Templates

Comment: Generating the HTML server side is quick, efficient and easy. But it can be difficult if you're really trying to generate full tables. Also, I forgot another option: You can create a Partial View which only contains a single dropdownlist, then you can render that partial by passing a Model to it. There are many options to choose from as you can see :)

Answer (score 1):

As you have noted, PageMethods are static. There is no way for a static method to manipulate instance members without having an instance to work with.

Furthermore, you have to understand that your page instance doesn't exist after the request has completed. There *are* no instance members to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to carry state information forward from one request to another, you can't do that with Page instance variables (a Page instance only exists for the duration of a single request)--and you shouldn't use statics, either.

One correct approach is to have your Ajax, etc, code update Session state. There are other possibilities if you can't or don't want to use Session state.